# 2013 Workflows Not Working for a Particular Site - Token Service Issue

Tags: 2013, workflow, security-token-service

**Update with additional information**.

- This is not limited to the Send an Email action. No 2013 Workflows work anywhere on this site.

  - I Tried a simple one to set the value of a field.  Same error.
- Wrapping the action in an App Step did not solve my issue.

  - Ensured Workflows can use App Permissions Site Feature is Enabled
  - Granted Full Control for workflows in Site App Permissions as outlined in a response.
- A **2010 workflow** performing the same action to set a value of a field **did** work.

### Original Post Below

I have a site that the ‘Send an Email’ action, simply does not work with a 2013 Workflow.  When I review the workflow under: Item – Workflows – Running Workflows, it has an internal status of ‘started’ with the information icon aside of it. When this icon is clicked, I get a long error message (see end of post for the message in it’s entirety).  The focal point for me in the message states the following:

> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was
>   canceled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to fetch an
>   access token from the token service. The token service returned an
>   error type of 'unauthorized_client' with the following description:
>   AADSTS70001: Application with identifier
>   'f83f69d4-ac79-4d90-a785-9df044b97f06' was not found in the directory
>   a544b575-cd97-4b77-9957-2d709aa16a55

This message is received when attempting to build a 2013 workflow on any list within the site.

**Troubleshooting steps taken thus far:**

- I Used the ShareGate Migration tool and migrated the list and the
  associated workflow to another site.  The workflow does not generate
  this error and successfully sends emails.
- I created a new list with a 2013 workflow with a single action (send
  an email) in a single stage to email myself.  I start the workflow
  and receive the same error.
- The parent site does not have this issue.
- Other sites under the same parent do not have this issue.
- Creating a 2010 workflow gets around this but I would like to stay
  with using only 2013 workflows.

**Environmental Notes:**

- We are using SharePoint Online.
- Site was created in 2010 on premise, upgraded to 2013 on premise
  while running in 2010 mode and then migrated with ShareGate Migration
  to SharePoint Online.

My testing so far has pointed me in the
   direction of a site issue and not a list/workflow issue.

> Activity in progress
>
> Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
>   Details of last request: HTTP  to [My companies site
>   URL]_api/web/lists(guid'0ace938d-d157-4645-9685-82d7a3c4e2b8')
>   Correlation Id:  Instance Id: 65f83329-9cb8-4f62-b63f-27cb6a2e79dd
>
> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was
>   canceled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to fetch an
>   access token from the token service. The token service returned an
>   error type of 'unauthorized_client' with the following description:
>   AADSTS70001: Application with identifier
>   'f83f69d4-ac79-4d90-a785-9df044b97f06' was not found in the directory
>   a544b575-cd97-4b77-9957-2d709aa16a55 Trace ID:
>   0981db0d-9d89-4da1-a13d-ab1165afa38c Correlation ID:
>   49a10622-bd57-05c8-a028-1d40bee29a29 Timestamp: 2017-03-16 17:20:01Z
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.FetchAccessToken(Uri
>   stsUri, String targetServiceAudience, String authenticatorToken,
>   HttpWebRequest request, TimeSpan timeout, EventTraceActivity
>   eventTraceActivity, TimeSpan& expirationDuration)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.FetchAccessToken(Uri
>   stsUri, String targetServiceAudience, String authenticatorToken,
>   HttpWebRequest request, TimeSpan timeout, EventTraceActivity
>   eventTraceActivity, TimeSpan& expirationDuration)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.GetAccessTokenFromTokenService(OAuthS2SPrincipal
>   client, OAuthS2SPrincipal targetServiceAudience, HttpWebRequest
>   originalRequest, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity, TimeSpan&
>   expirationDuration)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SSecurityTokenServiceCredential.GetAuthorization(OAuthS2SAuthenticationChallenge[]
>   bearerChallenges, HttpWebRequest request, EventTraceActivity
>   eventTraceActivity)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateInternal(String
>   challenge, WebRequest request, OAuthS2SCredential credential,
>   EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Security.OAuthS2SAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String
>   challenge, WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)    at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationManagerDefault.Authenticate(String challenge,
>   WebRequest request, ICredentials credentials)    at
>   System.Net.AuthenticationState.AttemptAuthenticate(HttpWebRequest
>   httpWebRequest, ICredentials authInfo)    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmitForAuth()    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckResubmit(Exception& e, Boolean&
>   disableUpload)    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DoSubmitRequestProcessing(Exception&
>   exception)    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(CoreResponseData
>   coreResponseData)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.HttpRequestWorkItemAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result, Int32& responseCode)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)

Answer (score 0):

Try to develop the `Send an Email` workflow action inside an `App Step`.

[image]

**Note:** By default, the workflow doesn’t have permissions to access the list where the Workflows generally run at permission level equivalent to write.So you should also make sure that the Workflow permission has been elevated by doing the following:

- Allow workflow to use app permissions.
- Grant full control permission to a workflow.
- Develop the workflow to wrap actions inside an App Step using SharePoint Designer.

For more details about How to apply the above steps check [The Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I followed the steps outlined in the provided link but I am still receiving the same error as before.  Also, it is important to note that the status of my workflow remains as **started** unlike the issue identified in the article where the status of the workflow is **suspended**.